# Inverse Operations with Exponent and Sum

Tags: calculus, inverse

Struggling with this inverse operations formula (that I can't seem to remember since leaving college). Solve for $X$.

$$X^{\frac 12} + X = 5$$

Comment: Easily substitute $x=t^2$ and go forward

Comment: $$x=5.5\pm\sqrt {5.25}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $$\sqrt{x}=5-x$$ after squaring we obtain
$$x=25-10x+x^2$$  solve this equation and check the Solutions

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{x}+x=5 \iff \sqrt{x}=5-x \iff x=25-10x+x^2 \iff x^2-11x+25=0$$

as long as $x\geqslant 0$.

Now use the quadratic formula to get an explicit formula for $x$.